# My /tmp/cook file is going crazy?

Tags: php

Currently, after 10 days or so after cleaning up my /tmp/cook directory, there are 3657 session files

```
vm645:/tmp/cook# ls | wc -l
3657
```

so I assumed they're not cleaned up itself.

Snippet of my php.ini

```
session.save_path = "/tmp/cook"
session.use_cookies = 1
session.use_only_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain =
```

so I assume it should be cleaned automatically. I think this one is also related with cleaning up

```
; After this number of seconds, stored data will be seen as 'garbage' and
; cleaned up by the garbage collection process.
; http://php.net/session.gc-maxlifetime
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.gc_probability = 0
session.gc_divisor = 1000
```

am I missing something? What do I need set in order to force PHP clean up that directory after a while (but not to kill live sessions?)

My PHP version is PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze3 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jun 28 2011 08:24:40)

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? If it's not at least 4.2.3, you should upgrade. Otherwise, PHP relies on `atime` updates, which may not happen.

Comment: PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze3 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jun 28 2011 08:24:40)

Comment: How about the `session.gc_probability` and `session.gc_divisor`?

Comment: @quanta updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that a session will get cleaned up is equal to `session.gc_probability / session.gc_divisor` (with the exception that it'll never get cleaned up until `session.gc_maxlifetime` has passed); the short version is that you need to make `session.gc_probability` non-zero.

Docs are [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability).

Comment: Perfect, I'll look tomorrow and tell you how does it work